# CreateAPIView error: `create()` must be implemented

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

My code:
serializers.py:

```
class AuthenticationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True)
    def validate(self, data):
        email = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')
        user = User.objects.get(email=email, password=password)
        if user is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'A user with this email and password was not found.'+ ' ' + email + ' ' + password
            )
        return  {
            'email': user.email,
            'username': user.username,
        }
```

views.py:

```
class Authentication(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AuthenticationSerializer
    def authentication(request):
        user = request.data.get('user', {})
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return user, Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I need to create authentication and after give user JWTToken but I can't to do authentication. I am work with this libs 2 days. May be it is because I am using `CreateAPIView`? But what can I replace CreateAPIView?

Comment: Your serialzer is not a `ModelSerializer` hence there is no method for `serialzer.save()`, you thus should define one if you want to create items.

Comment: I need to authenticate before i created JWT token, because i can't create JWT token if user didn't authenticate.

Comment: I think you need to rename `authenticate()` to `create()`. However, I suggest using `django-rest-framework-simplejwt` rather than implementing authentication yourself.